# Render ASP.Net user controls parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls, async-await

Is it possible to render two user controls in aspx page in parallel. It seems like even though the data load is defined as async other user controls does not render while one user control is waiting for data to load.

I have a `CustomGridView` control which is inherited from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView` . In my aspx page I have several 
CustomGridViews to be rendered . And also In my aspx page the page is defined as `async=true` ,

```
public class CustomGridView : GridView{
   //...
   protected override void OnPagePreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(GetDataAsync));
        base.OnPagePreLoad(sender, e);
   }
   private async Task GetDataAsync(){
       var data=await _service.GetDataAsync();
       this.DataSource=data;
       this.DataBind();
   }
    //...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't expect this to ever be possible as the rendering of ASP.NET WebForms controls might be dependent on the order of the rendering and where on the control tree they are.

However, that doesn't prevent the loading of all data sources in parallel before the rendering.

Comment: the issues is all datasources dosn't seems to be loaded parallel , because datasource.databind() is called from each user control itself . And then it waits for the data to load.

Comment: If you're extending `GridView`, isn't that a custome control? User controls extend `UserControl`.

Comment: Why don't you bind the data in the page code instead of the control code?